# Can I use aria-required="true" on html select tag.

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, accessibility

The aria-required attribute can be used to ensure required fields are conveyed correctly to assistive technologies. Can I use it for html select tag which is required? like: `<select aria-required="true"><option></option></select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5, you **can** use `aria-required`, but you **must** use the `required` attribute for non assistive technology users.

When you use the `required` attribute, you do not need the `aria-required` attribute (except if you want to target some old browsers not supporting HTML5).

Answer (score 2):

Just to back Adam up with a reference, see the [official W3 spec for the <select> tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-select-element).  Under "content attributes" it lists that the required property is valid.  So if you use that property, then as Adam said, you don't need to use aria-required.